# Drop down menu appears on top of menu when display:table used

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Below is the screenshot of my site. The dropdownmenu appears on top of the main menu and more space added around the dropdown too. All happen because I used display:table for ul and display:table-cell for li. How do I rectify it please? Also, I'm using foundation ,the following problem I think related to foundation specific css.  If you look at the dropdown menu, they appear from the right to the left when hover but I want the other way round. That is to appear from left to right ,left align with the parent menu.

[image]

Here's how I want to achive

[image]

This is the link to the site : http://fspb.valse.com.my/

Thanks in advance people.

Comment: *The threat Mal/HTMLGen-A has been found on this website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.top-bar-section .right li .dropdown {
left:-21px;
}

.top-bar-section .dropdown {
top:40px;
}
```

Remove right:auto from *.top-bar-section .right li .dropdown*

You can find these Css Styles in app.css

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the exact classes.. I managed to push the dropdown below...but how to get rid of the space around each dropdown menu?

Comment: what did u try for that?

Comment: Im trying to remove padding-bottom for .top-bar-section right li .dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution to your problem

```
.sub-menu .dropdown{
  top:40px;
}
.sub-menu ul li a{
  line-height: 25px!important;
}
```

Where sub menu is your class defined for the hover menu Which has top as 50px; which needs the top as 40px and The line height was 40px; so we need to reduce it to 25px; in order to achieve it. Besides make sure !important where it will override the foundation framework property

Comment: ...I'm really sorry. Can u tell me the exact class plz by refering to the source code...I just can't get it right

Comment: <ul class="sub-menu dropdown"> Here sub-menu & dropdown are the classes i am talking about